# the css file will not load in my html webpage

Tags: html, css

Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

    </head>
<body>
   <div class="nav-container">

       Hi


   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my css code:

```
.nav-container {
  height: 197px;
  background: #24292d;
}
```

I've got a folder called 'main.css' which holds the 'style.css' file. The 'main.css folder is in the same directory as the html file but for some reason the css wont load onto the web page.

[image]

Comment: If it's called `style.cc` then there's your problem.

Comment: ????where is that

Comment: @coderoftheday rename the file to `style.css` Not `style.cc`

Comment: ohhh my bad i mean to say "style.css" thats not the problem, ill edit the question now

Comment: @coderoftheday `I've got a folder` where is the html file same location as `style.css`

Comment: Not sure about the `.` in your path `./style.css`

Comment: @B001ᛦ — If its in the same path, it's fine.

Comment: the html file is in the same location as the main.css folder, then inside the folder holds the "style.css" file

Comment: @coderoftheday try this => `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`

Comment: @Quentin thank you. Everyday learning something new

Comment: not working @AlwaysHelping

Comment: `I've got a folder called 'main.css' ` problem could be here as this does not make any sense to me - i am not sure about others.

Comment: tried removing the folder and placing the css in the same location still didnt work

Comment: @coderoftheday Can you show us your Full directory like draw it or screenshot ?

Comment: i just edited the question with the picture

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />` change this to the path of the `style.css` file.

Comment: The `href` attribute needs to point at the URL of the stylesheet. There's no way of telling, from what you've provided, what URLs the web server assigns to either the page generated from the template or the CSS file.

Comment: still not workng, im using flask python by the way

Answer (score 1):

just make things simple.

have your folder set up like this

home/index.html

home/css/styles.css

then :

```
 <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: "The 'main.css' folder is in the same directory as the html file". So the code to reference the CSS file from the html file should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css/style.css">
```

But I wouldn't name a *folder* 'main.css' - this would typically be a name for a CSS file (including it's file extension `.css`), not a folder

Answer (score -1):

If your HTML file is in the same directory as your `/main.css/` folder, then change your file path to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Read the comments above.

Comment: Have you tried to test this before posting as an answer?